# Cannot resolve identifier from Cocoapod Xcode 7.2.1 Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, cocoapods

I've been following [this tutorial religiously](https://www.raywenderlich.com/99386/create-cocoapod-swift) which is verified for Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7.1 *(as per the title I'm using Xcode 7.2.1 Swift 2.2)*, so I get stuck on the article "Using Your New CocoaPod" where you've implement it. I followed it along precisely, and my app delegate look like this:

```
import UIKit
import RWPickFlavor

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?
  var rootViewController: UIViewController!

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
    launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

      setupRootViewController()

      window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
      window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
      window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

      return true
  }

  func setupRootViewController() {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: PickFlavorViewController.self)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: bundle)
    rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
  }
}
```

but I have an error on the following line:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: PickFlavorViewController.self)
```

The error message reads: "Use of unresolved identifier 'PickFlavorViewController'"

Has something happened in between swift 2.0 and 2.2 affecting the CocoaPods and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you didn't copy the PickFlavorViewController into your project, which is mentioned in your tutorial:

*Now drag and drop everything — except for AppDelegate.swift and LaunchScreen.xib — from the above groups in IceCreamShop.xcworkspace into the corresponding groups in RWPickFlavor.xcworkspace like this:*

Copy the controller and all should be fine. Good luck!

Comment: I did indeed copy it over and I'm looking at the file as I type. I followed the tutorial to the letter, apart from the custom bits like my git repo url.

Comment: It looks like you were on to something after all, it was indeed an issue with the copying of the file.

Answer (score 1):

## The Beginner's guide to Making your CocoaPods

The issue I had here, despite following the tutorial to the spot was that when I copied the files over, **they were moved into the root folder of my Swift cocoa pod project folder in my filesystem**. This is why I go the error message that my class couldn't be found.

### NOTE!

Just because you made a group in your xcode project it does not mean that Xcode will make any kind of folder architecture in regards to that.

Xcode's project structure is a pointer-based system that points to a file no matter where it is in your computer's file system. Moving it in Xcode does not move it in the folder!

In my case the files were copied into the root folder and per default the pod with look into the folder named like your project that's located in the root folder, but it won't see what's in your root and therefor not find the files when you use the pod.

## How do I fix it?

In your root folder *(the one where you can find the `RWPickFlavor.xcworkspace`)* of your pod project you have a folder with the same name as your project. **Move all your swift files into that folder.**

Update your pod to accomondate your changes:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Refactored the files (Or whichever commit message you want here)'
git tag 0.2.0
git push origin master --tags
pod repo push RWPodSpec RWPickFlavor.podspec
```

And in your Ice Cream Shop project root *(Once again, where you find the `[ProjectName].xcworkspace`)* run a pod install with your updated pod.

Some of these pod steps may be unnecessary, but this is what I did to solve my problem.